# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: jquery, token

May i know whats wrong in this.I am new to world of programing ..So if you help me it would be wonderful.The error comes on the line

> arr[${i.count-1}][1]=${employee.email};

Awaiting  for your response.The entire Code as follows..

```
$(function() {  
   var arr = new Array();

   arr[0]=new Array(4);
   arr[0][0]=sathis;
   arr[0][1]=sathis@gmail.com;
   arr[0][2]=namakkal;
   arr[0][3]=21;

   arr[1]=new Array(4);
   arr[1][0]=ganesh;
   arr[1][1]=gans@gmail.com;
   arr[1][2]=karaikudi;
   arr[1][3]=22;

   arr[2]=new Array(4);
   arr[2][0]=karthik;
   arr[2][1]=karthik@yahoo.co.in;
   arr[2][2]=trichy;
   arr[2][3]=25;

 var str="<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>City</th><th>Age</th></tr><tr><td>";

 $("#emp_name").change(function() {
     var i=$(this).val();
    str=str+arr[i-1][0]+"</td><td>"+arr[i-1][1]+"</td><td>"+arr[i-1][2]+"</td><td>"+arr[i-1][3]+"</td><tr></table>";
    $("#viewer").html(str);
    alert(str);
    });


});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need quotes for strings.
For example, you need `arr[0][0]='sathis';` instead of `arr[0][0]=sathis;`

Also, there's an easier way to do arrays:

```
arr[0] = ['sathis', 'sathis@gmail.com', 'namakkal', 21];
```

Comment: I just had the same ILLEGAL error but it appears to be from pasting text into Coda and allowing it to change the UTF format.  Needed to type the same code by hand and it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

As [user:638452] pointed out, this could be a bad invisible character. Backspaced over an invisible character where Javascript told me the error was, and my code worked without modification.