# jQuery 1.10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470306/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669954/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855250/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal). And a lot of other locations on the Web. But no solution.

I'm trying to add inline javascript with this script:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var j=jQuery('<div />');
  });
</script>
```

On my [webpage](http://www.olivierpons.fr/2008/05/07/mysql-astuces-pour-quelques-ordres-de-base/), [here](http://www.olivierpons.fr/2008/05/07/mysql-astuces-pour-quelques-ordres-de-base/), which includes latest jQuery, I have two problems:

1. I can't use `$`: I have to use jQuery otherwise I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function`
2. If I type the code below: the call to `var j=jQuery('div.content');` it is ok and I can do 'console.log(j);' If I try just to change `div.content` by `<div />` to create a new `div` like this `var j=jQuery('<div />');` then I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. I cant explain why, because there's no "strange character" or anything strange I'm doing here.

Anyone

Comment: The syntax error is not in the code you provided here which is syntactically valid. Please provide the relevant code. If you don't know what code is relevant to a syntax error - please consider reading about the developer tools as they can tell you that.

Comment: For 1.: `$.noConflict(); jQuery(document).ready(function($){ var j = $("<div />");});` - [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: @benjamin If i remove only the line or replace "<div />" by "div.content" it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code from the said page

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var j=jQuery('
<div />');
    console.log(j);
});
```

you have a line break after `'`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var j=jQuery('<div />');
    console.log(j);
});
```

Comment: The problem comes from Wordpress: even though I was editing my article in **raw** mode, Wordpress keeps on modifying the text, thinking he may always be more intelligent than the writer.